# how to convert a clusterw .dnd file to image (png) file?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to create png images from dnd file for better understanding of dnd file.I have seen some software which convert dnd files to image format and I have around 2000 dnd file and I want to convert those file into image file for better understanding

Is it possible to create phylogenetic tree image from clusterw dnd file?

one example of the dnd file is like bellow:

```
(
(
A:0.336889,
(
(
B:0.204161,
(
(
(
C:0.112841,
(
D:0.0605849,
E:0.0605849):0.112841):0.133598,
(
F:0.0946236,
G:0.0946236):0.133598):0.148107,
H:0.148107):0.204161):0.285724,
I:0.285724):0.336889):0.338734,
J:0.338734):0.338734;
```

Comment: first: yes, it is possible .... second: from documentation "ClustalW produces .DND and .PHB files which TREEVIEW can read. The bootstrap values in .PHB trees are stored as labels for the internal nodes. These can be viewed using the Show Internal Labels command." ....

Comment: view [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/17023/)

Comment: As I mentioned I have seen some treeview software which can show a dnd file in image format.But I want to know to the program behind it and as I have 2000 dnd file  it is not easy to create  all image file from dnd.

Comment: I understand ..... can you  upload, input dnd example?, please

Comment: sure .. But I cant able to see any option in the stackoverflow for uploading file other than image .SO what should I do??copy paste the dnd file content??

Comment: yes , copy and paste if not very long

Comment: I have added one example.

Answer (score 5):

you may use [ape library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/index.html) in R, dnd file is a type of [Newick format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format)

```
install.packages("ape")

library(ape)
MyTree <- read.tree("my_file.dnd")
png("my_file.png")
plot(MyTree)
dev.off()
```

you get:

[image: phylogenetic tree]

or, if you prefer use [phytools library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phytools/index.html), Note: before, you must first remove line breaks to input file

```
((A:0.336889,((B:0.204161,(((C:0.112841,(D:0.0605849,E:0.0605849):0.112841):0.133598,(F:0.0946236,G:0.0946236):0.133598):0.148107,H:0.148107):0.204161):0.285724,I:0.285724):0.336889):0.338734,J:0.338734):0.338734;
```

```
install.packages("phytools")

library(phytools)
MyTree <- read.newick("my_file.dnd")
png("my_file2.png")
plot(MyTree)
dev.off()
```

you get

[image: phylogenetic tree 2]